# pandas – "multiplication table" for each row with custom function

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with cities coordinates, like this (example):

```
  x  y
A 10 20
B 20 30
C 15 60
```

I want to calculate their distance : sqrt(x^2 + y^2) from each other with sort of a multiplication table (example):

```
  A  B  C
A 0 20 30
B 20 0  25
C 30 25 0
```

How can I do this? I've tried using `apply` function but need some guidance.

Comment: whats wrong with just doing `df['c'] = (df['x] ** 2 + df['y'] **2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [broadcasting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html) feature in pandas, together with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['distance'] = (df['x'] ** 2 + df['y'] ** 2).apply(np.sqrt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) of scipy:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[10,20,30], 'y': [20,30,60]},index=list('ABC'))

pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df,df), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

Output:

```
           A          B          C
A   0.000000  14.142136  40.311289
B  14.142136   0.000000  30.413813
C  40.311289  30.413813   0.000000
```

Comment: @lkky7: Did this solve your problem? If so please consider accepting the answer, if not please comment. Thanks.